# How to concat string to List C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to add the strings to the List and export the list as csv file but the result I got is not the way I want. Here is the code -

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        List<string> lineValues = line.Split(',').ToList();
        var tempMinInt = 1;
        var tempValue = 1;
        var tempValInt = Convert.ToInt32(lineValues[4]);
        if (tempValInt % 60 != 0)
        {
            tempMinInt = (tempValInt / 60) + 1;
            tempValue = tempMinInt * 30;
        }
        else
        {
            tempMinInt = tempValInt / 60;
            tempValue = tempMinInt * 30;
        }


        values.Add(lineValues + "," + tempValue.ToString());

    }
}
```

Here is the sample input data:

```
33083,2011-12-19 05:17:57+06:30,98590149,1876,258
33084,2011-12-19 05:22:28+06:30,98590149,1876,69
33085,2011-12-19 05:23:45+06:30,98590149,1876,151
33086,2011-12-19 05:30:21+06:30,98590149,1876,58
33087,2011-12-19 06:44:19+06:30,949826259,1876,66
```

And here is the output data:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],150
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],60
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],90
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],30
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],60
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you should check out File.ReadAllLines in the System.IO namespace. It make importing files line-by-line much easier.

Comment: It also make it synchronous, so you shouldn't use that for large files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` does not override `ToString`, so you'll need to do the leg work here.

You can use string.Join to combine the values of the list into a comma separated string:

```
string.Join(",", lineValues.ToArray());
```

Your last line of code posted above will become:

```
values.Add(string.Join(",", lineValues.ToArray()) + "," + tempValue.ToString());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Alternatively, you can just use `line` in this code snippet, as `lineValues` is built from `line` and you aren't modifying any of the values.

Comment: Will it affect the performance if the input data is quite large?

Comment: Potentially,  I don't have any data on performance myself.  You can run your own tests to see.

Comment: It works!

But could you tell me if there's any difference between lineValues.ToArray() and just lineValues?

And also, if I want to skip the first row of the input data, how can I do it?

Comment: `string.Join(",", lineValues.Skip(1));`

Comment: @Ye Myat Aung `lineValues` is a `List<string>`. The `.ToArray` method copies the data to a `string[]` array which the `string.Join` method takes as an argument.  Serge is correct.  You can use `.Skip(1)` to skip the first row.  You'll still need to call `.ToArray` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I want to skip the first row of te input data at the beginning before I do any calculations (because it contains characters).

Answer (score 2):

.NET is trying to turn a List of strings into a string, and it doesn't know how to do this implicitly. I think you should check out string.Join, and use it like:

```
values.Add(string.Join(",", lineValues) + "," + tempValue.ToString());
```

This will turn the list of strings into a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `string.Join(",", lineValues)`

Try this:

```
values.Add(string.Join(",", lineValues) + "," + tempValue.ToString());
```

Also, this won't work if any of those line values contain characters that need to be escaped.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685705/good-csv-writer-for-c) for a solution to escaping characters.