# Writing/Parsing library for CSV with unknown number of columns

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, filehelpers

I am trying to follow everybody's advice and use a library for my CSV writing/parsing needs. But the most recommended, `FileHelpers`, needs a column-mapping class. However, I just need to read write single lines of comma separated values, then parse them back later. I can't find a way to use FileHelpers or other libraries in this simple way.

For example, I make a `String testInput = "\"yoyo\",\"yaya\",\"te\"\"st\"";` as input, and want to parse it into a `String[]` with values `yoyo`,`yaya`,`te"st`.

Also I need to do the opposite, writing the values back to the string like this `"yoyo","yaya","te"st"`.

Does anyone know of a library that can do this or how I can use for example FileHelpers for this?

I don't really want to do xml because of the amount of "junk" characters involved in xml fields (bandwidth/storage limitations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSV reader on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) should handle that; just turn off the file headers and use `new StringReader(line)` on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: Can this library also do writing arrays to csv?

Comment: @David not sure, but see my comment on Vyktor's post; *writing* CSV is much much easier than *reading* it

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer because `TextFieldParser` as suggested by Vyctor is apparently very slow.

Answer (score 2):

[`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128079.aspx) should be able to do the job, [`ReadFields` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields.aspx) which is defined as:

> > > Reads all fields on the current line, returns them as an array of strings, and advances the cursor to the next line containing data.

I found nice example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser).

As for writing CSV, I'd use different method that I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685745/1149736). It seems to be the simplest method that doesn't require importing 3<sup>rd</sup> party extension.

Comment: Thank you, but I also need a writer to correctly convert fields to csv, so that is only half of the solution.

Comment: @David writing CSV is easier than reading it - especially if you want all the values quoted (as in this case). Replace `\"` with `\"\"` and append+prepend `\"` - job done.

Comment: @David there's no CSV writer class simple enough for you... But I've added a link that I found.