# cvshelper > writing custom rows before WriteRecords?

Tags: c#

```
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        //HERE I NEED TO WRITE SEVERAL CUSTOM ROWS LIKE,
//DATE
//NAME
//COMMENT
//CLASS
//

before the actual bulk of data

        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
```

```
I have tried:
csv.writecomment("");
csv.writerecord("");
csv.writeheader(<myObject>);
```

but all of these write the data in the very first row, I've also tried to add "\r\n" but didn't work either.

any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to print the column names/headers?

Comment: either [CsvHelper : Adding a title using CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238544/csvhelper-adding-a-title-using-csvhelper) or [Writing a Header using CsvHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088379/writing-a-header-using-csvhelper-c-sharp). I will vote for dupe of both.

Comment: @DragandDrop thank you. that was it. I've added writefield followed by a nextrecord after each field I wanted to get before the whole batch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CsvHelper : Adding a title using CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238544/csvhelper-adding-a-title-using-csvhelper)

Comment: @DragandDrop yes. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

question solved by the suggestion of @DragandDrop.

```
 using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {

        csv.WriteField(TITLE_VAR);
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteField(TITLE2_VAR);
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteField(TITLE3_VAR);
        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
```