# How to create a CSV file and write data into in f#

Tags: f#, f#-data

How can i can i create a csv file in f sharp and write the following record type in it?

```
    type test = { G:array<double>; P:array<double>; GG:array<double>; PP:array<double> } 

    let table = [for x in 0..(Un0.Length - 1) -> 
        let b = Un0.[x] in 
        if b=0.0 then {G=0.0; P=0.0; GG=0.0; PP=0.0}
        else {G=G_0.[x]/b; P=P0.[x]/b; GG=G0.[x]/b; PP=PP0.[x]/b}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To record in .csv is not necessary to use F# Data.

I changed the definition of test and added some values so that you can compile:

```
type test = { G:double; P:double; GG:double; PP:double }
            override this.ToString() = 
                sprintf "%f;%f;%f;%f\n" this.G this.P this.GG this.PP

let G_0  =  [|(0.0)..(10.0)|]
let Un0  =  [|(1.0)..(11.0)|]
let P0   =  [|(2.0)..(12.0)|]
let G0   =  [|(3.0)..(13.0)|]
let PP0  =  [|(4.0)..(14.0)|]

let table = [for x in 0..(Un0.Length - 1) -> 
                let b = Un0.[x] 
                if b=0.0 then {G=0.0; P=0.0; GG=0.0; PP=0.0}
                else {G=G_0.[x]/b; P=P0.[x]/b; GG=G0.[x]/b; PP=PP0.[x]/b}]

let wr = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Csv.csv")
table |> List.map(string) |> String.concat("") |> wr.Write
wr.Close()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: where is this file "Csv.csv" saved?

Comment: @HaagenDaz, Near with .exe file. But you can specify any path: System.IO.StreamWriter(PathToFile)

Comment: can we use this on arrays rather than list?

Comment: @HaagenDaz, For random access by index, arrays will work much faster than lists. Therefore it is better to use arrays.

Comment: in your answer above if i need to create a record type table from the dummy arrays you created `G_0 Un0 P0 G0 PP0` would it be simply table={G=G_0;P=Un0...}? and also how can i clear the data in existing csv file before writing new data

Comment: @HaagenDaz, 1. If I understand the question, then, yes     
2. By default, If the file already exists, it is overwritten.
I see that you have a few simple questions, in my view, them are much easier to solve in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: @FoggyFinder For general CSV writing it would preferable to use a library such as FSharp.Data as it will take care of escaping for you. For this specific data there is no problem though if we ignore localization.

Comment: @Răzvan Panda, Thanks, could you tell more about this?

Comment: @FoggyFinder See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684717/750216 One of the comments has a link to the CSV specification. Some countries use , instead of . so printing floats containing a , will break the CSV format.

Comment: @Răzvan Panda, thank you. You are right, so I used ';'. Need to see how recording is implemented in special libraries.

Comment: This is not an RFC 4180 compliant CSV. It does not handle text and special character escaping for example. Also even the separator character is not a coma. Decimal points are locale dependendt. It may work with Excel on your machine (which has a notoriously bad CSV implementation), but will not result in portable CSV output.

Comment: @kódfodrász `This is not an RFC 4180 compliant CSV. It does not handle text and special character escaping for example` That's for sure. I personally would use library like `CsvHelper` but in trivial cases straightforward approach isn't that bad.

Comment: @kódfodrász `Also even the separator character is not a coma. Decimal points are locale dependendt.` That's exactly the reason why I used `;` as a separator.

Comment: In the stackoverflow post it cannot be seen what your CurrentCulture is.

I had to deal with too much garbled data created by "trivial cases" that turned otut to be non-trivial, to never ever suggest the printf approach.

If it is to be read by excel, it doesn't amtter, as Excel currently still cannot handle most of the corner cases solved by RFC compliant implementation anyway. (LibreOffice does handle CSV well)

Comment: @kódfodrász `In the stackoverflow post it cannot be seen what your CurrentCulture is.` cause it's unrelated to the answer. But answering to your Q: CurrentCulture on my machine has a`,` as separator character for float numbers.

Answer (score 24):

The [CSV type provider from FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) is primarily known and used for reading CSVs (as the name suggests), but it's also quite capable of *writing* CSVs as well.

All you need to do is to define the type, either by providing a sample .CSV file

```
let titanic2 = CsvProvider<"../data/Titanic.csv", Schema="Fare=float,PClass->Passenger Class">.GetSample()
```

or by directly defining the schema

```
type MyCsvType = CsvProvider<Schema = "A (int), B (string), C (date option)", HasHeaders=false>
```

then you can create a record object and populate it (in a type-safe way!)

```
// you can build the rows themselves
let myCsv = new MyCsvType( [ MyCsvType.Row(1, "a", None)
                             MyCsvType.Row(2, "B", Some DateTime.Now) ])

// or, for your scenario, you probably want to define a conversion function
// from your record type to the CSV provider's type
let buildRowFromObject obj = MyCsvType.Row(obj.A, obj.B, obj.C)

let buildTableFromObjects = (Seq.map buildRowFromObject) >> Seq.toList >> MyCsvType

let myCsv = someSequenceOfObjects |> buildTableFromObjects
```

and finally, just call

```
myCsv.SaveToString()
```

to get the output in CSV format.

Comment: Is there a way to infer the csv format from an existing type (sort of automatic mapping/schema definition)?

Comment: where would this csv be saved?

Comment: > where would this csv be saved? 

The `.SaveToString()` method returns a string, and saving that to a wherever is up to the caller.

To save to a disk locally the `.Save()` function is available, which requires either a string with the path, or a TextWriter or a Stream argument where the contents will be written.

See at: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/545c0eb89547e7ad29657bd18ec7a4df3b78c292/src/Csv/CsvRuntime.fs#L315

Note that internally `Save` and `SaveAsString` create a `StringWriter`/`StreamWriter` with default settings, thus it uses platform default newlines.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answer to your question, but it is similar and could be handy

## How to EDIT csv file with f#  CSV Type Provider

### Solution:

```
#r "..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.3.3\lib\\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

type CsvTest = CsvProvider<"""C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.csv""">
let textReader = File.OpenRead("""C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.csv""")// need to use TextReader
let csvTest = CsvTest.Load(textReader)
let modified = csvTest.Append [CsvTest.Row(3,"bum") ]// add row to csv
textReader.Close()// closing file before edit...
modified.Save   """C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.csv""" //save it
```

You may need to **Reset Interactive Session** (if you work with fsx)

### Explanation:

Straightforward file loading like this:

```
let csvTest = CsvTest.Load("""C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.csv""")
```

Does not work. If you try it you will get error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.csv' because it is being used by another process.'

So I use TextReader, that can be closed..

Maybe there is easiest solution, but I didn't find any.