# How do I create dynamic type providers based on user input?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I want to allow users to provide complex objects, i.e `System.Diagnostics.Process[]`.

I see the documentation of type providers for JSON, CSV, HTML, etc. but I didn't see any type providers for normal Microsoft classes and the documentation to create a type provider appears to be manual.

For example, to create a CSV file Tomas Petricek gave the below code in [How to write a CSV in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51111590/how-to-write-a-csv-in-f)

```
type MyCsvType = CsvProvider<Schema = "A (int), B (int), C (float), D (int), E (int), F (int)", HasHeaders = false>

let myCsvBuildRow (x:Family) = 
  MyCsvType.Row(x.Month,x.Year,x.Income,x.Family,x.Dogs,x.Cats)
let myCsvBuildTable data = 
  new MyCsvType(Seq.map myCsvBuildRow data)

let myCsv = family |> myCsvBuildTable
myCsv.SaveToString()
```

I could get all process from my machine and manually set the headers, etc. But if I want to get the services, I would need to do it again.
As Microsoft classes are known, is there an option to create a type provider based on the objects properties dynamically?

Ideally the code should look like this:

```
let processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()

type MSCsvType = CsvProvider<Schema = System.Diagnostics.Process, HasHeaders = true>
MSCsvType(processes)
MSCsvType.Save("Path\To\Save\processes.csv")
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Could you provide some sort of pseudocode showing how you would use such provider if it existed?

Comment: Hi @FyodorSoikin, I added some code. I have never written type providers but it looks to me a very manual task. To create a new type provider ad hoc every time the object changes doesn't scale well.

Comment: @Alex_P type providers are only running at compile time.
You can save your csv chema in text file and give the path to that file for type provider. This will not make it work in runtime however.
There is an article that shows how to hack compiler to treat value as literal, but I didn't tried it: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/florencedev/exploring-f-literals-current-approaches-sneaky-trick